# Is signal function safe enough to just ignore or restore signal handler?

Tags: c, linux, unix, signals

I have read many articles which suggest using `sigaction` to replace of `signal` for many reasons. But after reading some open source code (Such as `Redis`, `Lua`), I find the `signal` still exists.

If I only use  `signal` to ignore or restore default handler, such as:

```
signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);
```

or:

```
signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_DFL);
```

Is `signal` safe enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`man 2 signal` on Linux says:

> The  only  portable  use  of signal() is to set a signal's disposition to SIG_DFL or SIG_IGN.

So yes, for the particular uses you're asking about, it's OK.  Still, there seems to be little advantage over using `sigaction()` if that is available on the platforms you care about.

Comment: Maybe this is only applicable on Linux. Right?

Comment: The advice applies to any platform, assuming you expect your code to be portable to Linux as well.